# Reverse query on django extended user profile

Tags: django-models, django-views

I have extended `User` via `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` to include a `ManyToMany` field to Projects the user is involved in.

I want to reverse the relationship, and get the Users associated with a given Project.

My users have profiles (I've successfully returned them with `related_projects = u.profile.projects`).

`related_users = project.userprofile_set.all()` is giving me something - `{% for user in related_users %} {{ user }}  {% endfor %}` yields `User Profile for: richlyon`. But I can't get `{{ user }}` to yield any fields. I've tried `{{ user.username }}`.

Question: am I going about this the wrong way? And if I'm not, how do I get field information out of a reverse relationship on an extended User profile?

Thanks as always for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'profile' object is not a `User`, nor is it extending `User` (in an object-oriented sense). Rather, it's a separate model that has a `ForeignKey` to a `User`.

User > Profile > Projects

In the code you posted, it looks like you're expecting a `User` object to be returned from the `project.userprofile_set.all()` query set.  However, these are going to be your intermediate profile objects from which you can then access the user.

Something like this:

```
related_profiles = project.userprofile_set.all()

{% for profile in related_profiles %} 
    {{ profile.user.username }} 
{% endfor %}
```